# How to redefine an existing Q_PROPERTY as REQUIRED?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

### Goal

I have a [`QQuickItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html) derived C++ class, `Foo`, and I would like to ensure, that whoever uses it in QML, gives a value to the [`objectName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property. In `Foo` I am redefining the property like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString objectName READ objectName WRITE setObjectName NOTIFY objectNameChanged REQUIRED)
```

Since [`objectNameChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectNameChanged) does not take zero arguments, this alone leads to an error. So I need to also add a signal to `Foo`:

```
void objectNameChanged();
```

Then it compiles without errors.

### Problem

The [documetation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) states:

> In QML, classes with REQUIRED properties cannot be instantiated unless all REQUIRED properties have been set.

However, when I use it like this in QML:

```
Foo {
    // objectName: qsTr("test) <-- commented line
}
```

the program compiles and runs without errors.

### Question

Is there a way to change the `objectName`, or any other existing property for that matter, to `required`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to expose a qml file Foo.qml which contains

```
CppFoo {
    required objectName
}
```

instead of exposing the C++ class directly to your users. Doing that for instance with a simple Item, and using it in another file would then lead to an error like

```
file:///tmp/tmp.aOQi2yetXl/Foo.qml:3 Required property objectName was not initialized
```

The fact that
`Q_PROPERTY(QString objectName READ objectName WRITE setObjectName NOTIFY objectNameChanged REQUIRED)` did not work is probably a bug in the engine. And there's currently no feature in the C++ API to mark the property of a parent's class as required.

Comment: I hope the issue is going to be addressed in Qt6 and I am looking forward to it. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, for me this solution does not work. I have added `required objectName` in a qml item and it still compiles and runs without an error.